# How to write custom listerner to beforeupdate evnt in grails domain classes

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-domain-class

I want to write custom listeners for `beforeUpdate` event for domain classes:
I've lot of domain classes in my project.
I want to create custom listener and  in that on `beforeUpdate` event of every domain class I want to perform some logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can set global `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate` in `BootStrap.groovy` like:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClass

class BootStrap {

  def grailsApplication

  def init = { servletContext ->
    grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { GrailsDomainClass gc ->
        gc.metaClass.beforeInsert = {
            log.debug "beforeInsert"
            //code here
        }
        gc.metaClass.beforeUpdate = {
            log.debug "beforeUpdate"
            //code here
        }
    }
  }

  def destroy = {}
}
```

---

---

And if you want to perform different action for some domain class and different for other then

```
grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { GrailsDomainClass gc ->
    if(gc.metaClass.javaClass.equals(User) || gc.metaClass.javaClass.equals(Role)){
        gc.metaClass.beforeInsert = {
            log.debug "beforeInsert"
            //code here
        }
        gc.metaClass.beforeUpdate = {
            log.debug "beforeUpdate"
            //code here
        }
    } else ...
}
```

Comment: Inject `grailsApplication` buddy.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Extending @user1690588's answer, you can also cherry pick domain classes where you want to have `beforeInsert` events using:

```
grailsApplication.getDomainClass('com.myapp.MyDomain')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject service into domain class and call service method on beforeUpdate event. And use the same service method for several domain classes.
Domain class:

```
class TestDomain {

    transient testService

    def beforeUpdate() {
        testService.testMethod()
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
class TestService {

    def testMethod() {
        // Custom logic goes here
    }
}
```